# How do I compare base36 values in C++?

Tags: c++

As we all know, with C-style string comparisons, the value is dependent on the ASCII value of each character and just uses the `strcmp` function to compare. I'm confused that what the `std::string` compare depends on?

Although I have searched Google, I still didn't find the answer.

In addition, if strings are all base36 strings and they are all in lower case, could I compare their values by strings directly? Or I should convert them as a long variable using the `strtol` function? Which method is better?

Comment: When you say compare base36 do you mean for equality or for higher/lower?

Comment: If you compare `000AA` with `00ZZ`, you have to be careful because the shorter string sorts numerically after the longer string.  Otherwise, though, you can basically do Base-36 comparisons on length and then a string comparison on strings of equal length.

Comment: "base36 strings" doesn't make sense. You probably mean that it's a number, where each digit with the base 36 is stored in a string. Now, think about how you compare numbers in general. With that info, you should be able to work out how to compare two numbers with that representation, too.

Comment: thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2):

Your outset "As we all know, with C-style string comparisons, the value is dependent on the ASCII value of each character..." is unfortunately wrong already. With e.g. UTF-8 strings and various forms of collation, that's simply untrue.

Then "...and just uses the strcmp function to compare." is also wrong, because C-style strings don't have an inherent way to compare but multiple ways that also depend on e.g. the encoding and locale. You could use `strcmp()` for bytewise equality comparisons though, but that won't always give you expected results.

To answer your question what `std::string` uses, that's simple. `std::string` is a specialization of the `std::basic_string` template and it delegates comparisons to its `char_traits` template parameter. This parameter typically uses `memcmp()`. It can not possibly use `strcmp()`, because other than a C-style string, `std::string` can include null chars, but `strcmp()` would stop at those.

Answer (score 1):

std::string compare depends upon 'ASCII values' in exactly the same way that strcmp does.

For base36 comparisons, simple string comparison (either strcmp or std::string) doesn't work because "00123" and "123" are equal when representing base36 integers but they compare differently as strings. Neither does strtol work very well because of integer overflow. Instead you should probably write your own comparison routine that removes leading zeros, then compares length and finally for strings of equal length does a string comparison.

Comment: if you're writing your own compare function you may as well just make it self-contained, by the time you've skipped the zeroes you're all set up just to loop and compare